# Проблема с аргументами в запросе sql

Tags: c++, sql, c++builder, access

Здравствуйте! Есть БД на ADO и Access. Моя задача - по нажатию на button отфильтровать таблицу сразу по двум полям: значение первого поля вводится в Edit1, значение 2-ого задается через код. Пока сделал следующий код, но он не работает, ругаясь на аргументы. Перепробовал множество вариантов, но ошибка все та же.

```
ADOTable1->Filtered = false;
ADOTable1->Filter = "Tip LIKE '"+Edit1->Text+"%' AND Rezultaty LIKE 'Не пройдена'";
ADOTable1->Filtered = true;
```

Вопрос: что не так с аргументами и как это можно исправить?

Comment: 1) где ошибка? 2) выведи запрос который получает access, увидишь сам в чем причина, учись дебажить. и да, я бы поставил пробел перед Tip, раз там так тупо фильтры делаются

Comment: @strangeqargo если я все правильно сделал, то ошибка в LIKE, но я не представляю, что в нем не так

Comment: @strangeqargo Undeifined symbol 'Rezultaty'

Answer (score 1):

вы перепутали MySQL/Postgres/прочие SQL и MS Access. знак `%` не имеет смысла для Access.
вместо него надо использовать символ `*` (`?`, `#`)
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php

Comment: Поменял на знак "*", все равно не ищет.

Comment: Undeifined symbol 'Rezultaty'